# Simplifying Hide/Show with multiple selectors to show when clicked and individually

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me simplify this code snippet? I would like to be able to write less lines of code instead of repeating the same code with different selectors ( sounds like a loop, but I don't know how to do it).

The problem when I put multiple classes separated by commas, they do not show the hidden content individually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//hide show toggle Latest 

$(".more-text-latest, .more-text-latest-2").hide();

$(".read-more-latest").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
$(".more-text-latest").slideToggle(600);
      $(this).toggleClass(".more-text-latest");
    });

$(".read-more-latest-2").click(function(){
$(".more-text-latest-2").slideToggle(600);
      $(this).toggleClass(".more-text-latest-2");
    });
```

Comment: Is this a JavaScript-only app or do you have some example HTML?

Comment: I am building this : http://codepen.io/dhouglasc/pen/vymMxL - it is a simple website with just some coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a loop that does the same thing there are several ways to achieve it, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hide show toggle Latest 
    [
        '.read-more-latest',
        '.read-more-latest-2'
    ].forEach(function (selector) {
        var moreTextSelector = selector.replace('read-more', 'more-text');
        $(moreTextSelector).hide();

        $(selector).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(moreTextSelector).slideToggle(600);
            $(this).toggleClass(moreTextSelector);

            if ($(this).hasClass(moreTextSelector)) {
                $(this).html('Return');
            }
            else {
                $(this).html('Read More');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works beautifully! I will reapply the code to the rest of my project. But it is still a bit complex to me. Especially the part where you call the event to preventDefault. Can you help me understand where -1 and -2 come from?  I haven't studied events yet. 

THANK YOU BUNCHES, HYDDAN!

Comment: ps. What if I wanted to change READ MORE to let's say RETURN once it is clicked and vice versa. Can we add that to your loop? Or do I have build another block?

Comment: The line with the -1 is just a shorthand for an if statement, if the left side of && is true then the right side of the && will run, otherwise it will not. In your sample code you called preventDefault() in the handler for '.read-more-latest' but not in the one for '.read-more-latest-2' so that indexOf checks if the string '-2' exists in the selector and if it does not then indexOf will return -1 and preventDefault() will be called.

Regardless, I believe you don't even need that line and can remove it altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the second thing there, do you want to change the text of the button once it is clicked to say 'Return'?

Comment: Hey Hyddan, thank you again. you are being very helpful. You are right I need the button once clicked to say 'Return'.  Could you please check What I did wrong below? I tried reapplying your code to the other part of the code and it is not working. I split in two comments.

Comment: [
        '.read-more-gallery-1',
        '.read-more-gallery-2',
  '.read-more-gallery-3',
  '.read-more-gallery-4'
    ].forEach(function (selector) {
        var moreTextSelector = selector.replace('read-more-gallery', 'more-text-video');
        $(moreTextSelector).hide();

        $(selector).click(function (e) {
            // As your example, only call e.preventDefault() when selector does not contain '-2'
            -1 === selector.indexOf('-4') && e.preventDefault();

Comment: $(moreTextSelector).slideToggle(600);
            $(this).toggleClass(moreTextSelector);
        });
    });
 });
  
$(document).ready(function(){

Comment: So, I updated the answer to also switch the the text between 'Read More' and 'Return'. I also removed the conditional execution of preventDefault(). I still think you won't need preventDefault() so you could just try removing that and see if things still behave correctly but I left it there since you had it from before. Regarding the other two comments there, perhaps it is just the formatting making it look odd but it looks like you have the line: $(document).ready(function(){ after the other code. Your code should be inside this function, like $(document).ready(function(){ [YourCodeHere] });

Comment: Thank you Hyddan! Everything is working beautifully. I am just beginning my journey of learning to code. It's funny to see  you know the commands, but still don't know how to put things together. Any studying source recommendations or advises?

Comment: Glad to be able to help, if this solves your current issue you might consider marking the answer as accepted. As for reading material, there is an abundance out there but personally I find that just trying things out is a great way learn. Nevertheless, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ is a good reference to check out what javascript functions do and of course, Stack overflow is a great place to find answers/examples for questions about anything programming related really.